# Remove unintentionally created object versions in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I've changed the storage type from S3-Standard to S3-INT for all objects in the bucket, not being aware that versioning was turned on.

Now, I have a old version for each object in S3-standard for each object in S3-INT, effectively doubling my S3 costs.

Here's an example how the versions for an object in the console looks like:

[image]

Is there a way to **immediately** delete the old versions either through the console, CLI or python SDK?

I've been reading in the docs that I could do this using a life-cycle-policy. But If I understand it correctly, this would only delete them at a minimum on the following day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why your version ID is null. Regardless, you can use the AWS CLI to delete a specific version of an object.

[V1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/delete-object.html)

```
aws s3 delete-object --bucket my_bucket --key object_key --version-id version_to_delete
```

[V2](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3api/delete-object.html)

```
aws s3api delete-object --bucket my_bucket --key object_key --version-id version_to_delete
```

See the reference [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/delete-object.html) and [here](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3api/delete-object.html) for the aws cli, and [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.delete_object) for boto3. If you're using boto3, you can iterate the versions of the object and delete them iteratively.

Comment: Maybe you can add that is works with CLI version `1.x` - with version `2.x` the call changes to `aws s3api delete-object`

Answer (score 2):

You would have to write a script or something to query for all the files and all versions of those files, and issue a delete command for the previous versions. The only automated built-in way of doing this is lifecycle rules.